# Surface Tension Mathematics

Tags: surfaces, fluid-dynamics

Is there a mathematical way of calculating the dispersion of the particles that move apart when surface tension is broken by dropping a small drop of liquid soap on the water? (The classical experiment showing the surface tension.)

Comment: This could be cross listed with physics to help you get a clear answer, as the mathematics will be found in fluid dynamics. The fundamental equation for this process might be the diffusion equation

Comment: @ Aditya Jha Like the image of separating droplets in my profile here?